# Ordenar uma lista de objetos por mais de um atributo

Tags: java, collection, comparação

Como ordenar uma lista de objetos por mais de um atributo? Em primeiro é feita a ordenação da pontuação, depois como critérios de desempate temos o numero de vitória e depois o saldo de gols.

Algo assim:

```
Pontuacao pontuacao = new Pontuacao(pontos, vitórias, saldo de gols);

List lista = new List();

Pontuacao timeA = new Pontuacao(14, 6, 20);

lista.add(timeA);

Pontuacao timeB = new Pontuacao(18, 3, 21);

lista.add(timeB);

Pontuacao timeC = new Pontuacao(14, 6, 22);

lista.add(timeC);

Pontuacao timeD = new Pontuacao(15, 7, 11);

lista.add(timeD);

lista.sort;
```

Resultado:

1º) timeB // Maior pontuação

2º) timeD // Segunda maior pontuação

3º) timeC // Maior saldo de gols

4º) timeA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer essa ordenação, você pode utilizar o método `sort` da classe `Collections`. Através dele, você pode criar uma lógica de ordenação em bloco:

```
List<Pontuacao> pontuacoes = new ArrayList<>();
    pontuacoes.add(new Pontuacao(14, 6, 20));
    pontuacoes.add(new Pontuacao(18, 3, 21));
    pontuacoes.add(new Pontuacao(14, 6, 22));
    pontuacoes.add(new Pontuacao(15, 7, 11));

    Collections.sort(pontuacoes, new Comparator<Pontuacao>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pontuacao lhs, Pontuacao rhs) {
            if(lhs.getPontos != rhs.getPontos)
                return Integer.compare(lhs.getPontos(), rhs.getPontos());
            else if(lhs.getVitorias() != rhs.getVitorias())
                return Integer.compare(lhs.getVitorias(), rhs.getVitorias());
            return Integer.compare(lhs.getSaldoDeGols(), rhs.getSaldoDeGols());
        }
    });
```

Seu objeto Pontuação pode, inclusive, implementar a interface `Comparable<T>` para que este código fique mais organizado:

```
class Pontuacao implements Comparable<Pontuacao> {
    private int pontos;
    private int vitorias;
    private int saldoDeGols;

    public Pontuacao(int pontos, int vitorias, int saldoDeGols) {
        this.pontos = pontos;
        this.vitorias = vitorias;
        this.saldoDeGols = saldoDeGols;
    }

    public int getPontos() {
        return pontos;
    }

    public void setPontos(int pontos) {
        this.pontos = pontos;
    }

    public int getVitorias() {
        return vitorias;
    }

    public void setVitorias(int vitorias) {
        this.vitorias = vitorias;
    }

    public int getSaldoDeGols() {
        return saldoDeGols;
    }

    public void setSaldoDeGols(int saldoDeGols) {
        this.saldoDeGols = saldoDeGols;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull Pontuacao another) {
        if(another.getPontos() != getPontos())
            return Integer.compare(another.getPontos(), getPontos());
        else if(another.getVitorias() != getVitorias())
            return Integer.compare(another.getVitorias(), getVitorias());
        return Integer.compare(another.getSaldoDeGols(), getSaldoDeGols());
    }
}
```

Então, o sort fica simplicado:

```
List<Pontuacao> pontuacoes = new ArrayList<>();
    pontuacoes.add(new Pontuacao(14, 6, 20));
    pontuacoes.add(new Pontuacao(18, 3, 21));
    pontuacoes.add(new Pontuacao(14, 6, 22));
    pontuacoes.add(new Pontuacao(15, 7, 11));

    Collections.sort(pontuacoes);
```

Comment: A gente estava ensinando o OP a pescar em vez de dar o peixe... e também a lógica da comparação está incorreta.

Comment: ...ou não. L:^)

Comment: Para que servem os setters? Para poder alterar a pontuação depois que a lista foi ordenada e assim invalidar a ordenação? Já que sugeriu o código completo, sugiro sugerir uma classe imutável para o objeto Pontuacao.

Comment: @Caffé, os setters são resultados de um plugin de geração de classe com getters/setters que eu usei para criar o exemplo. Não me preocupei em remover os mesmos, ou criar a classe na mão. Peço desculpas por criar a resposta com código. Se quiserem, removo

Comment: Não há o que se desculpar, @IgorCastañedaFerreira. A resposta é sua (você manda) e está boa.

Answer (score 3):

Faça sua classe `Pontuacao` implementar a interface `Comparable<Pontuacao>` e implemente nela o método `compareTo()`.

Exemplo com dois critérios, sendo o critério 1 mais importante e o critério 2 menos importante:

```
public int compareTo(Pontuacao outro) {
    int resultado = outro.getCriterio1() - this.getCriterio1();
    if (resultado == 0) {
        resultado = outro.getCriterio2() - this.getCriterio2();
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

[Por que não tem uma checagem por null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858628/comparable-and-comparator-contract-with-regards-to-null)?

Comment: Foi o que pensei e vi em uma série de exemplos, mas a dúvida é como ordenar por mais de um atributo seguindo a ordem de importância. Como o Order by do sql.

Comment: No `compareTo` você irá comparar dois times pelo número de pontos. Se forem iguais, irá comparar segundo a maior pontuação. E se a pontuação for igual, irá comparar pelo saldo de gols. No final terá que retornar um número negativo, positivo ou zero, dependendo do resultado das comparações.

Comment: @caezar Você ordena por mais de um atributo do mesmo jeito que ordena por um único atributo - apenas terá mais de uma condição na comparação. Se você viu exemplos, atualize sua pergunta com o que você já conseguiu fazer até agora.

Comment: Bom, com o peixe dado, vou complementar a resposta.