# Ordenação de ArrayList em Java

Tags: java, collection

Eu preciso ordenar esse ArrayList com base em dois parametros

```
ArrayList<Imovel> listaImoveis = new ArrayList<>();

public class Imovel {
private String bairro;
private int valor;
```

Eu primeiro preciso ordenar o ArrayList com base na ordem crescente de cada bairro e depois na ordem crescente de valor dentro de cada bairro

Eu ja fiz o comparator do bairro, mas n sei como irei fazer para ordenar os valores dentro dos bairros

```
public class OrdenarBairros implements Comparator<Imovel> {
    public int compare(Imovel o1, Imovel o2) {
        if(o1.getBairro().compareTo(o2.getBairro()) > 0) {
            return 1;
        }       
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Ordenar uma lista de objetos por mais de um atributo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42540/ordenar-uma-lista-de-objetos-por-mais-de-um-atributo)

Comment: Tem essa também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/452429/112052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer de outra maneira este comparator, não precisa criar uma classe nova.

A seguir vou apresentar um exemplo para que compreenda melhor.
Vou utilizar a seguinte classe *TesteOrdDupla* para representar a classe em que é feita a ordenação, sendo o atributo *e1* como elemento mais importante na ordenação e o *e2* como o segundo mais importante.

```
class TesteOrdDupla {
   Integer e1;
   Integer e2;

   public TesteOrdDupla(Integer e1, Integer e2){
       this.e1 = e1;
       this.e2 = e2;
   }
}
```

Agora, neste próximo trecho de código, vou inicializar uma nova lista com objetos desta classe criada anteriormente e adicionar alguns elementos.

```
List<TesteOrdDupla> listOrd = new ArrayList<>();
listOrd.addAll(Arrays.asList(new TesteOrdDupla(1, 2),
         new TesteOrdDupla(2, 2), new TesteOrdDupla(2, 3),
         new TesteOrdDupla(2, 4), new TesteOrdDupla(3, 3),
         new TesteOrdDupla(5, 3), new TesteOrdDupla(7, 8),
         new TesteOrdDupla(4, 5), new TesteOrdDupla(7, 10)));
```

Finalmente, após já ter a lista devidamente preenchida, vamos para a parte de ordenação. Nesta resposta, vou apresentar duas maneiras diferentes de resolver este problema, mostrados a seguir:

1. Utilizando a interface *Comparator* sem precisar criar uma nova classe:

   ```
   Collections.sort(listOrd, new Comparator<TesteOrdDupla>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(TesteOrdDupla i1, TesteOrdDupla i2) {
           // Caso os elementos mais importantes dos dois objetos comparados 
           // forem iguais, os segundos mais importantes serão comparados
           // Caso contrário, será realizada a comparação dos mais 
           // importantes(bloco else)
           if(i1.e1.equals(i2.e1)){
               return i1.e2.compareTo(i2.e2);
           } else {
               return i1.e1.compareTo(i2.e1);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   De forma mais compacta, o código acima pode ser reescrito como:

   ```
    Collections.sort(listOrd, new Comparator<TesteOrdDupla>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(TesteOrdDupla i1, TesteOrdDupla i2) {
           return (i1.e1.equals(i2.e1) ?
              i1.e2.compareTo(i2.e2) : i1.e1.compareTo(i2.e1));
        }
   ```
2. O segundo método que irei mostrar é utilizando a parte funcional do java, implementado no java versão 8, com funções lambdas. Da mesma forma que o método anterior, os argumentos da função lambda *i1* e *i2* referem-se a objetos do tipo *TesteOrdDupla*, assim, a função anônima definida dentro do bloco retornará um valor igual a `-1`, `0` ou `1`, sendo, respectivamente, *e1* menor que *e2*, *e1* igual à *e2* e, finalmente, *e1* maior que *e2*.

   ```
    Collections.sort(listOrd, (i1, i2) -> {
       // Esse bloco de código é o mesmo do mostrado anteriormente
       if(i1.e1.equals(i2.e1)){
           return i1.e2.compareTo(i2.e2);
       } else {
           return i1.e1.compareTo(i2.e1);
       }
    });
   ```

   Ou, similarmente ao anterior, podendo ser reescrito como:

   ```
    Collections.sort(listOrd, (i1, i2) -> {
       return (i1.e1.equals(i2.e1) ?
          i1.e2.compareTo(i2.e2) : i1.e1.compareTo(i2.e1));
    });
   ```

Como resultado deste código, você irá obter uma lista ordenada primariamente por *e1* e, em caso de empate, ordenada por *e2*. A saída do código acima será a seguinte lista, com seus elementos separados por `|`, o atributo *e1* de cada elemento como o primeiro valor em cada bloco e o *e2* como o segundo valor:

`1 - 2  |  2 - 2  |  2 - 3  |  2 - 4  |  3 - 3  |  4 - 5  |  5 - 3  |  7 - 8  |  7 - 10`

**Qualquer dúvida comente abaixo!**

Comment: Eu entendi obrigado mano
Mas eu tenho mais uma pergunta
Lambda é muito usado para essas coisas? Eu ja li sobre, mas não dei muita importancia por não achar muito necessário
Mas valeu mesmo

Comment: @BatmanVascaino
As funções lambda são utilizadas em várias partes da programação, desde Collections à implementação de Threads.
Assim, o principal motivo de utilizar esse tipo de função é que não é necessário declarar uma nova função para um algo que será utilizado, provavelmente, só naquela ocasião. Além disso, deixa o código, de certa forma, mais organizado.
Te sugiro dar uma lida em funções lambda porquê são extremamente úteis e necessárias para um código bem feito. Dito isso, na parte de collections, sugiro aprender sobre a API Stream do java, já que é implementado muita coisa útil lá.